# Power bi gateway only for one source

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

I've a power bi report and I want to connnect it to a csv with import mode and to sql server with direct query option.

I want to upload this report in te power bi service, so use the data on the csv importe and the directquery mode via on premise gateway.

When i upload the report on the power bi service, when I configure the gateway there is the option for the sql server and the options for the offline csv... And the system dont let me select only the sql server option.

[image]

Here I've one option for sql server that i can connect with the gateway and have it running properly. But I've another option that is the csv imported with import mode, that I don't want to connect through the gateway because it is static data... The problem is that if i dont choose a gateway for both sources, the apply button is greyed out.

Thanks

Comment: Please share screenshot of power bi service.

Comment: Load the CSV into a dataflow. Do not set up a schedule for the dataflow so it remains static, use that in the report. The SQL DB will use the connection and not worry about the data gateway, and if the static data ever changes you can update it